# Regex. Match word until pattern containing space and line

Tags: regex

I got a text line like this:

SOMENAME (KEYONE(any chars) - KEYTWO(consist of numbers) - KEYTHREE - KEYFOUR) - KEYFIVE

I need a regex to extract the keys. The seperator between the keys are "

**spaceLineSpace**

".

I got this working for everything exept KEYONE. The problem is that KEYONE, could contain either 
spaces or lines(not both at the same time) like this:

- SOMENAME (KEY-ONE - KEYTWO - KEYTHREE - KEYFOUR) - KEYFIVE
- SOMENAME (KEY ONE - KEYTWO - KEYTHREE - KEYFOUR) - KEYFIVE

The problem is the first key, I've tried these two expressions so far:

- `^(\\s-\\s]+` 
  Works fine for both characters and numbers, but break if KEYONE contain a space or a line.
- `(a-z0-9]+` This works with number and space, but break if KEYONE is just numbers.

If I can't make this work, Im going to do a stringsplit instead.

All help is appreciated! :)

Full Code:

```
     Regex emailregex = new Regex("(?<DOCCLASS>[^( - $ ]+) - (?<DOCNO>[^ - ]+) - (?<DOCSHEET>[^\\s-\\s]+) - (?<DOCREV>[^\\s-\\s)]+)");
        string title = "MY%20TITLE.DOCM%20(10 003%20-%201202827%20-%201%20-%20A2)%20-%201";

        String decodedTitle = Uri.UnescapeDataString(title);// //Server.UrlDecode(documentSharepointTitle);




        Match m = emailregex.Match(decodedTitle);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DOC_CLASS: " + m.Groups["DOCCLASS"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("DOC_NO: " + m.Groups["DOCNO"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("DOC_SHEET: " + m.Groups["DOCSHEET"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("DOC_REV: " + m.Groups["DOCREV"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("DOC_TYPE: " + m.Groups["DOCTYPE"].Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(decodedTitle + " , does not match document title pattern.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue...");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are asking a regex question without specifying whether your regex kind is Perl, EGrep, Javascript, Awk, Vim, … Please give more details!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^\w+\s\(([\w\s-]+)\s-\s(\d+)\s-\s(\w+)\s-\s(\w+)\)\s-\s(\w+)$
```

And btw...it would be a lot easier if you provided some examples. I'm not about to invent them myself, so I couln't really check, if it works as intended.